# Python - how do I target a class in another class using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am learning to create a crawler with beautifulsoup and Python 3, I encountered a problem, the data I want to get in a website has multiple class, here is an exemple:

```
<tr class="phone">
  <a href="..." class="number"></a>
</tr> 

<tr class="mobile">
  <a href="..." class="number"></a>
</tr>
```

---

And here is what I want to do with Python :

```
for num in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'mobile -> number'}):
    print(num.string)
```

What should I do to target the class `.mobile .number`?

Comment: Easiest way to go will be to first fetch all the "mobile" fields and then run a selector on them looking for "number".

Comment: I wonder how dictionary becomes a CSS selector, but you could try: {'class':'mobile > number'}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`soup.select`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to find items according to a [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = '''<tr class="phone">
  <a href="tel:+18005551212" class="number"></a>
</tr> 

<tr class="mobile">
  <a href="+13034997111" class="number"></a>
</tr> '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc)

# Find any tag with a class of "number"
# that is a descendant of a tag with
# a class of "mobile"
mobiles = soup.select(".mobile .number")
print mobiles

# Find a tag with a class of "number"
# that is an immediate descendent
# of a tag with "mobile"
mobiles = soup.select(".mobile > .number")
print mobiles

# Find an <a class=number> tag that is an immediate
# descendent of a <tr class=mobile> tag.
mobiles = soup.select("tr.mobile > a.number")
print mobiles
```

Comment: The difference in `>` and `' '` CSS selectors are `div > p` will only select `p` which are "immediate" children of `div`, while `div p` will select all `p`'s inside `div`, including grandchildrens. However if your HTML is like what you posted it's odd that `>` did not work.

Answer (score 1):

`find_all()` elements with class "number", then iterate through the list and print the one whose `parent`'s class is "mobile".

```
for dom in soup.find_all("a", "number"):
    # this returns a list of class names
    for class in dom.parent()["class"]:     
    if class == "mobile":
        print(dom.string)
```

or use `select()` for CSS selector style

```
for dom in soup.select("tr.mobile a.number"):
    print(dom.string)
```

Comment: why am I getting this error : `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` and with the select option there is nothing printed :/

Comment: @Sia my mistake `dom.parent()['class']` actually returns a list since an element can have many classes, thus another loop is needed there. I don't see any problem with `select` code.